# Multiple data-bind in knockout js

Tags: knockout.js

I have two text property data Date and City are observables.
I need to concatenate two text property data in single div.
and apply separate style for both the texts.
Current Scenario is used knockoutjs data-bind property :

```
<div class="date" data-bind="text:Date" />
<div class="city" data-bind="text:City" />
```

Expected :

```
<div class="date city" data-bind=" text:Date text:City" />
```

Output : ***2013-05-24*** New York

Please guide me how to do this.

Comment: Try it comma separated `data-bind="text:Date, text:City"`

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have tried with comma, only city name will be displaying.

Comment: Is there really a reason to focus on a single div ? like why you do not use 2 span in it and problem solved ?

Answer (score 35):

You can't use two of the same binding on an element.  Instead, you should create a computed which formats the text using the two values you want to display.

For example (Assuming your Date and City are observables):

```
viewModel.DateCity = ko.computed(function() {
  return viewModel.Date() + " - " + viewModel.City();
});
```

Then in your data-bind, you just bind to the computed.

```
<div class="date city" data-bind="text:DateCity" />
```

Another option is to combine the values in the binding directly.

```
<div class="date city" data-bind="text: Date() + ' - ' + City()" />
```

Personally I feel that the computed approach is a cleaner way to go.

Comment: I need to apply style for both the date and city.In the above example DateCity i am not able to apply styles.

Comment: The CSS classes have nothing to do with the text binding, which only controls the data which is displayed. You can still apply both CSS classes like I have above.

Comment: Computed is best approach, IMO. Another option would be to use knockout comments: `<!-- ko text: Date --><!-- /ko --> <!-- ko text: City --><!-- /ko -->`

Answer (score 11):

You can simply write :-

```
data-bind = "text: Date() + City()"
```

And if you want to add any string **ex:- 2013-05-24 : New York** , you can code as :

```
data-bind = "text: Date() + ':' + City()"
```

This way its worked for me.

Comment: This works as charm!

Answer (score 5):

To use separate styles for each part, you'll need separate HTML elements to attach those styles to. Using a `span` for each part would work.

```
<div>
    <span class="date" data-bind="text:Date"></span>
    <span class="city" data-bind="text:City" ></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

you could add 2 spans or call it like this

```
<div class="date" data-bind="text:Date() +' '+ city()" />
```

Answer (score 1):

use "," or "+" sign to do multiple data-bind.

```
<div class="date city" data-bind=" text:Date(), text: City" />


<div class="date city" data-bind=" text:Date() + City" />
```

Comment: @radim : i guess u forget to use () here `data-bind=" text:Date(), text: City"` i guess it should be `data-bind=" text:Date(), text: City()"`

Answer (score 1):

With [ko.punches](http://mbest.github.io/knockout.punches/) you could do

```
<div class='date city'>{{ Date() }} {{ City }}</div>
```

Just another option with a great plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this format:

```
data-bind="text: city() + ', ' + state() + ' ' + zipcode()"
```